# Auto-populate fields w/o Triggers

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

Is there any way to autofill custom fields without using a trigger while still using Apex code? I have fields that are aimed to be filled in based on more complex logic and accessing information of related list object information. I read something that I could make a VisualForce Page that will autopopulate the fields? In addition, the only use I know of for Apex Classes is calling them in Apex triggers. If there was a way for an Apex Class to initially fill in the fields based on my apex code, that would be ideal: I could run this class at any time I choose and my fields will be updated accordingly.

EDIT: for context, I have many contacts ALL of which I want to batch update certain fields. I do not want to use a trigger as that will only update the object associated with the insertion/update the trigger was fired upon. I want to use my code as a way to mass populate all objects fields based on some more advanced logic.

Any suggestions will help greatly.

Comment: Why don't you want to use triggers? Can you [edit] your question to be clearer about the design intent, user experience, sequence of operations you are trying to perform?

Comment: yeah, sure. no problem. Let me know if I am still not clear

Comment: @Sarah A formula field might work: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_formuladef.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect use case for [batch apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm)

You can create a batch class that loops through all your contacts and populates the fields based on the logic you define.

To run the batch, you have two options:

- Run in manually through the developer console using anonymous apex (which is a way of calling apex on the fly)
- Create a scheduled class that can call your batch class on a daily basis. See [apex scheduler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm)

Bonus: You mentioned you only know about apex being called from apex triggers. You can call apex classes from the following:

- visualforce pages through visualforce controllers
- anonymous apex
- batch and scheduled apex
- Via the process builder or flows